# Should I use Flow's exact types for components' props?

Tags: reactjs, types, flowtype

I'm using Flow to describe my components props. I would usually use it like so:

```jsx
class MyComponent extends Component {
  props: {
    user: { name: 'string' },
  }
  render () {
    return <div>{this.props.user.name}</div>
  }
}
```

Lately, we had some discussions in the office if it's better to define props in this way or rather using Flow's exact object types in which the `user` type would be defined like so `{| name: 'string' |}`.

I was wondering if there are some guidelines on when to choose one over the other.

Comment: You want to define a property of the `user` prop?

Comment: @Chris https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types

Comment: @AndrewLi, got it, thanks.

Comment: I personally would, considering it would offer better prop width checking to make sure the shape of the object was correct.

Comment: Here's the thing, if I try to use `this.props.user.email` Flow will complain in both cases. What exact types do is to prevent the component from receiving a "bigger" object, which I'm not sure is useful

Comment: @Gpx It's more about passing props to the component and checking if the prop type is correct, if the shape is correct, and if the correct props are passed.

Comment: In my understanding, it's possible to do that without explicit types. What I fail to see is when would I want to use an explicit type. I'm probably missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we decided to go with exact types so Flow warns us if we pass to an element more props than it needs.